# Service worker in a cross-origin iframe cannot intercept requests initiated by an iframe web worker on Mozilla Firefox (works on other browsers)

Tags: firefox, iframe, cross-domain, service-worker

I have the following app structure.

- `https://example-a.com`

  - index.html
- `https://example-b.com`

  - app.html
  - sw.js
  - worker.js

`example-a.com/index.html` loads an iframe from `example-b.com/app.html` which spawns a service worker and a web worker.

A web worker makes a network request to `example-b.com/intercept`. The service worker, the web worker and network request destination URL all belong to the same origin (`example-b.com`) and the request url belongs to the service worker scope (they are both at the root of the domain).

On Safari and Chrome, the service worker can successfully intercept such requests coming from a web worker. However, on Firefox such requests are not intercepted by SW.

It's worth mentioning that the service worker can successfully intercept requests made by the iframe html document and regular scripts. The issue I am having is specifically related to web workers.

I know that Firefox has some additional service worker restrictions (e.g. SW disabled in private mode), but I could not find any limitations related to my use case.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Is this a known Firefox limitation or a bug? Are there any headers that would help me with the issue?

[Reproducible example app repo (Github)](https://github.com/emilisb/ff-iframe-sw-test)

[Deployed example app](https://ff-iframe-sw-test.netlify.app/)

**Expected behavior**: service worker successfully intercepts the request and returns a modified response.

**Actual behavior**:

- Safari, Chrome - works as expected.
- Firefox - service worker does not intercept the request and an actual request to `example-b.com/intercept` is made.